# Как прибавить 1 день, если выполняется условие?

Tags: javascript, jquery

к переменной date2

```js
function parseDate(date) {
  const [d, m, y] = date.split('.');
  return Date.parse(`${y}-${m}-${d}`);
}

let date1 = '16.12.2021';
let date2 = '16.12.2021';

if(parseDate(date1) >= parseDate(date2))  {
console.log('gg')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Прям если сделать календарный счетчик на несколько месяцев - то автоматически никак, ведь у Вас дата является строкой, а не датой. 
Для начала нужно создать объекты типа Date, получать нужные компоненты из них, сверять и тогда будет счастье Вам)

https://learn.javascript.ru/date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать дополнительную функцию например. (ту, что между дефисами).
На первую `(function() {` не смотрите, я для автозапуска вашего кода ее написал.

```js
(function() {

  function parseDate(date) {
    const [d, m, y] = date.split('.');
    return Date.parse(`${y}-${m}-${d}`);
  }

  // --------
  function correctDate(date) {
    return date.replace(/^\d{2}(?=\.)/, (dd) => +dd + 1);
  }
  // --------
  
  let date1 = '16.12.2021';
  let date2 = '16.12.2021';

  if (parseDate(date1) >= parseDate(date2)) {
    date2 = correctDate(date2);
    console.log('date2', date2);
  }


})();
```

Comment: спасибо огромное